# How to use xslt copy preceding nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. I want to copy all the preceding nodes of one particular node, I tried with copy and preceding, but the output is not what I expected..

Source example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <MetaData>
      <Owner>adad</Owner>
      <date>2013-1-12</date>
   </MetaData>
   <Orders>
      <Order name="123">
         <OrderName>Order1</OrderName>
         <OrderNo>1</OrderNo>
      </Order>
      <Order name="1234">
         <OrderName>Order2</OrderName>
         <OrderNo>2</OrderNo>
      </Order>
      <Order>
         <OrderName>Order3</OrderName>
         <OrderNo>3</OrderNo>
      </Order>
   </Orders>
   <tail>1111</tail>
</root>
```

Xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match = "Orders" name="split">
    <xsl:for-each select="Order">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 2">
        <xsl:copy-of select="preceding::node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      adad
      2013-1-12


   <MetaData>
      <Owner>adad</Owner>
      <date>2013-1-12</date>
   </MetaData>
      <Owner>adad</Owner>adad
      <date>2013-1-12</date>2013-1-12


      <Order name="123">
         <OrderName>Order1</OrderName>
         <OrderNo>1</OrderNo>
      </Order>
         <OrderName>Order1</OrderName>Order1
         <OrderNo>1</OrderNo>1

      <Order name="1234">
         <OrderName>Order2</OrderName>
         <OrderNo>2</OrderNo>
      </Order>
   1111
```

expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
       <MetaData>
          <Owner>adad</Owner>
          <date>2013-1-12</date>
       </MetaData>
       <Orders>
          <Order name="123">
             <OrderName>Order1</OrderName>
             <OrderNo>1</OrderNo>
          </Order>
          <Order name="1234">
             <OrderName>Order2</OrderName>
             <OrderNo>2</OrderNo>
          </Order>
        <Orders>
   </root>
```

looks like the Descendant of `<MetaData>` and `<Order>` are copied three times..
And Why the `<tail>` node lost element name?

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to show your expected output in the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the first two nodes, why not select them explicitly in the for-each, eg. `select="Order[position()<=2]`?

Update: This will select all elements up to and including the second Order element:

```
select="*[count(preceding-sibling::Order) &lt; 2]
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not just copy Order node, I want to copy all the nodes before Order[2] (including itself)

Comment: `select="*[count(preceding-sibling::Order)<2]"` :)

Comment: I tried '<xsl:for-each select="*[count(preceding-sibling::Order) < 2]">' which throw an error..." The value of attribute "select" associated with an element type "xsl:for-each" must not contain the '<' character "

Comment: Try replacing `<` with `&lt;`.

Comment: @MichaelDay: Would you like to update your answer accordingly?